# pandas exporting to TZ time format in .json file

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time

I'm currently doing this to generate a dataframe:

```
 dataframe = pd.read_sql("select date_trunc('minute', log_time) as date, .....
```

my output is a time that looks like this:

```
"date":"2020-06-01 00:08:00.000"
```

What I want to do is have a time output that looks like this *in the json file that it is outputted to*:

```
"date":"2020-06-08T23:01:00.000Z
```

I found documents that show you how to remove it but not sure how to add it. do I have to do this after the dataframe is made or is there something in my date_trun( command that should put it in this format

Comment: What is your ultimate goal - to change the formatting within your jupyter notebook or when you output the data back to a csv, excel, SQL etc? If you are interested in changing the format, then you can change to a string with `strftime`: https://stackabuse.com/how-to-format-dates-in-python/

Comment: this data frame will output to a json . I dont know how to manipulate it in df so i can do a json.dum(df) and have the timeformat in the TZ format. I can manipulate it with strftime but not sure how to strftime in a query @DavidErickson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off our conversation in the comments section, I have edited your question and added `in the JSON file that it is outputted to` to the line `What I want to do is have a time output that looks like this in the` JSON `file that it is outputted to:` At the end of the data, the only thing that matters is the raw value to be accurate in your JSON file. Don't worry about what it looks like in your Jupyter Notebook. I think this is a common mistake that people make and one that I have made in the past as well.

I would suggest not worrying about the datetime format in pandas. Just go with pandas default date/time until the very end.

THEN, as a *final step*, just before exporting to a JSON, change the format of the field to:

```
df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f').str[:-3] + ['Z']
```

That will change to a format of `2020-06-08T23:01:00.000Z` .

Note `.str[:-3]` is required because `strftime` doesn't support milliseconds (3 decimals) according to the documentation and only `micorseconds` (6 decimals). As such, you need to truncate the last 3 decimals to change to millisecond format.

That specific format is not directly supported with `T` and `Z`, so I did a little bit of string manipulation.